# Unable to get country name from bunch of IP address in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, geolocation

I have a pandas dataframe `df_test` consisting of IP address like below :

```
     |  cs-username |   c-ip      |
     +--------------+-------------+
     |-             | 70.80.84.76 |           
     |-             | 70.80.84.76 |
     |-             | 70.80.84.76 |
     |-             | 70.80.84.76 |
```

My goal is to get the name of country from each of IP address,and I have used DbIpCity from ip2geotools.So I have written code like below.

```
from ip2geotools.databases.noncommercial import DbIpCity

#Your code
df_test['Country'] = df_test.apply(lambda row: DbIpCity.get(row['c-ip'],api_key='free').country, axis=1)
```

However this results in error like below :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3772268ef132> in <module>()
      2 
      3 #Your code
----> 4 df_test['Country'] = df_test.apply(lambda row: DbIpCity.get(row['c-ip'],api_key='free').country, axis=1)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ip2geotools/databases/noncommercial.py in get(ip_address, api_key, db_path, username, password)
     65         # format data
     66         ip_location.country = content['countryCode']
---> 67         ip_location.region = content['stateProv']
     68         ip_location.city = content['city']
     69 

KeyError: 'stateProv'
```

The code is in the below colab link (last cell) in case of reference:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zz1LZ2uOAp1YsX0x0CJfvcM21XGkeCO5?usp=sharing

So how can I resolve this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program throws a `KeyError` when it can't get any data about the IP address. To avoid the script from stopping, you could use an `exception`. But because the `ip2geotools` library has a request limit, I decided to go with [geolocation-db](https://geolocation-db.com) instead:
(I used a `for loop` instead of `lambda`)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib.request
import json

df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
countries = []
ips = []

# Get Country info from https://geolocation-db.com
def getCountry(ip):
  with urllib.request.urlopen("https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp/"+ip) as url:
    data = url.read().decode()
    data = data.split("(")[1].strip(")")
    return json.loads(data)['country_name']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Get IP data
    data = row['c-ip']
    if data not in ips:
        print(data)
        ips.append(data)
        #response = DbIpCity.get(row['c-ip'], api_key='free')
        response = getCountry(row['c-ip'])
        if response != None:
            print(response)

            # Add to country list
            countries.append(response)
        
        # If contry is None, add np.nan instead of None
        else:
            print(np.nan)
            countries.append(np.nan)

# Insert all data into a new df
ips = {'ip': ips,
       'country': countries, 
       }

df_ips = pd.DataFrame(ips, columns = ['ip', 'country'])    
print(df_ips)
```

And because your CSV file is soo huge, use a filter to avoid the processing of duplicate IPs.

And I found these errors in your Log:

```
ERROR: geoip2 4.1.0 has requirement requests<3.0.0,>=2.24.0, but you'll have requests 2.23.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: geoip2 4.1.0 has requirement urllib3<2.0.0,>=1.25.2, but you'll have urllib3 1.24.3 which is incompatible.
```

Try doing `pip install --upgrade requests urllib3`. You might have to upgrade them.

Comment: Instead of passing the 4 IP's can we pass the whole column of IP address from the dataframe i.e 'c-ip' ? I have lot of IP address stored in a column.

Comment: of course, u can add your own dataframe to it and it should work

Comment: I tried running your solution for a column of IP address (around 200k) but I'm still encountering the key error which I mentioned in the post.Any idea on why error did not happen in your above solution ?
Also, I tried updating urllib3 which you suggested but still error pops up.

Comment: On Google colab, link is in the post

Comment: I just tried my code in colab, and it works. Can u send me the csv file to try it out?

Comment: Thanks ! I'm getting Invalid request error now ! Is it due to issue from server side ?

Comment: Yeah I got the same thing. It's probably because of the many requests the script does to the IP lookup server

Comment: I would really appreciate it if u vote up my answer :))

Comment: Ah ! Sure, will upvote it, I will try to run the script after sometime and if the script runs I will mark your answer as the accepted solution :)

Comment: Thx man :) I will see if I find an alternative IP lookup library

Comment: Sure, please update your answer (along with existing one) in case you find alternative IP library.Would really like to see alternative (solutions) and it may be of help to others who are in need in future.

Comment: And one more, in your solution, instead of writing countries.append('not known') can we write countries.append('np.nan') ?

Comment: Of course, you can write anything u want. It would be countries.append(np.nan), without the ' '. I updated it!

Comment: Thanks, do you have any alternative IP library that does the same as DBIP ?.I have been trying but still getting invalid request error.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid `KeyError:'stateProv'`, in noncommercial.py:

.../ip2geotools/databases/noncommercial.py

Line 67 should be commented, and insert one line:
`ip_location.region = ''`

to make empty string for ip_location.region.

```
67      #ip_location.region = content['stateProv']

        ip_location.region = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an example of bash shell practices in my class:

$ whois 70.80.84.76|grep Country:|uniq|cut -d ':' -f 2

Comment: But this question was about Python, not bash shell Prof.

Comment: This ip2geotools has the limited number of IPs in a day for noncommercial library while this bash has no limitation. The right script for the right goal.

Comment: Agreed, that's the main limitation of ip2geotools.Thats why one of the answer suggested to use geolocation-db instead.